# Rails: My code causing "can't convert nil into String"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This code from my developer below... does it expect something like "1 - January" and try to parse it into something else?

I changed the code on my form so now the value being passed to this controller is just "1" instead of "1 - January"

How can I fix this so I don't get the "can't convert nil into string" error?

```
  def get_expiry_month_number(monty_det, expiry_year)
    if MONTH_NAMES.include? monty_det
       month_number = MONTH_NAMES.index(monty_det)
       month_number = MONTH_NUMBERS[month_number]
       expiry_year = month_number.to_s + expiry_year[expiry_year.length-3..expiry_year.length-1]
       return expiry_year
    end
  end
```

Comment: @ZMorek, it's a [range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Range.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are running into the problem that one of your strings in your calculation for year is nil. Most likely this one,

`expiry_year[expiry_year.length-3..expiry_year.length-1]`

You can try and fix this by calling `to_s` on the culprit variable, thus converting the nil into `''` and then concatenated.

Like so: `expiry_year = month_number.to_s + expiry_year[expiry_year.length-3..expiry_year.length-1].to_s`

However, this may have other seen consequences and isn't recommended. A better approach would be to find out why something you expect is a string is turning out to be empty, and perhaps displaying an appropriate error.

Could you explain a little bit more about what the function is supposed to do? And perhaps the value of `expiry_year` and `monty_det` when the error occurs? `puts` statements can be a big help here.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Here's the culprit code that is causing the nil error: 

`<%= select "payments", "expiry_month", User::MONTH_NAMES.collect{|x| [x, User::MONTH_NAMES.index(x) + 1] }, {}, { :class =>"sign-pay-lm1"} %>` 

Originally, the code author wrote that as `<%= select "payments", "expiry_month", User::MONTH_NAMES,{}, :class=>"sign-pay-lm1" %>`

I believe her logic was to turn "1 - January" or "6 - June" etc into the correct format for the payment gateway which must be MMYY format only.

She did it wrong so payments are not accepted.

Comment: I don't see get_expiry_month being called at all here. Why don't you try writing up a simple test case via irb, to try and figure out eaxctly which string is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `get_expiry_month_number('january', 2011)` would return: `1011`.

Indeed:

- `month_number` should return 1 for january
- `expiry_year[expiry_year.length-3..expiry_year.length-1]` returns the 3 last characters of `2011` => `011`

Comment: That seems like it doesn't make sense. Looks like an error on my dev's part... thank you

Comment: I really need to check on what that function is outputting, since I found that the API requires MMYY date format but months are being passed as 1, 2, etc... so June 2014 is 614 or.. if @apneadiving is correct, 6014... That would now make sense since the API is giving me an error "Expiration month of (60) must be between 01 and 12 "  EDIT just tested with May and it says (50)...